# find the roots $(2z+3)^3=\frac{1}{64}$

Tags: complex-numbers

There are 3 roots 1 real and 2 imaginary i found one z by doing $\frac{\frac{1}{4}-3}{2}$  so $z=\frac{-11}{8}$  however there are two more complex roots which are $z=\frac{-25+i√3}{16}$ and $z=\frac{-25-i√3}{16}$ but i dont know how to get to it any help is much appricated
. thank you

Comment: The two other roots are because of the complex cube root of $\frac{1}{64}$

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua but i dont understand how to get to it.

Comment: When solving $z^2-1$, there are two solutions, also when solving $z^3-1$ there are three solutions where are $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$, you'll need to understand complex numbers

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua i am on the chapter of complex numbers and am solving questions to understand it I have to see how it done to get it that's the thing.

Comment: Hi Sara. Are you familiar with the polar expression of complex numbers? If so, finding complex root of any complex number would be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @Ken Hung no do you think you can explain it since I am self studying I have no teacher for a-levels so I have to learn everything my self.

Comment: @Ken Hung i looked at it i belive I have done it but it was called something else but how is that related to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler method. Just use

$$\begin{align}a^3=b^3 \Longleftrightarrow a^3-b^3=0\Longleftrightarrow (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=0\end{align}$$

To find the complex roots, just  solve the quadratic:

$$a^2+ab+b^2=0.$$

---

In your case you can take $$a=2z+3, b=\dfrac 14.$$

Comment: but what would my a and b be for this question?

Comment: @Sara $a=2z+3, b=\frac 14$

Comment: I tired it multipule times i got $4z^2+13/2z+156/16=0$ andi keep getting it wrong

Comment: wait i solved it i had the z =25/2 and it was 157/16 but it took a lot of time to solve but thank you very much!

Comment: @Sara this is the algebraic way, which doesn't require to know any specific formula.

Comment: thank you very much you explained it so straight forward do you think you could look at my other question I asked it yesterday but no one could explain it. please

Answer (score 0):

$$(2z+3)^3=\frac{1}{64} \implies 2z+3=\frac{1}{4}, \frac{\omega}{4}, \frac{\omega^2}{4}$$
$$\implies z=\frac{-11}{8}, \frac{\omega -12}{8}, \frac{\omega^2-12}{8}.$$ Here $\omega$ is cube-root of unity.

Answer (score 0):

For any $z = a + ib \in \mathbb{C}$,

$$
z = \rho\left(\cos{\varphi} + i\sin{\varphi}\right),
$$

where

$$
\rho = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, \text{ and }\varphi = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right).
$$

Then,

$$
\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{\rho}\left(\cos{\left(\frac{\varphi + 2\pi k}{n}\right)} + i\sin{\left(\frac{\varphi + 2\pi k}{n}\right)}\right), \quad k = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1.
$$

In our example,

$$
\frac{1}{64} = \frac{1}{64} + i0, \text{ i. e., }a = \frac{1}{64}\text{ and }b = 0 \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\frac{1}{64} = \frac{1}{64}\left(\cos(0) + i\sin(0)\right) \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{64}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{64}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right)\right), \quad k = 0, 1, 2.
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
k = 0 \Rightarrow & z_1 = \frac{1}{4} \\
k = 1 \Rightarrow & z_2 = \frac{1}{4}\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = -\frac{1 - i\sqrt{3}}{8}\\
k = 2 \Rightarrow & z_3 = \frac{1}{4}\left(\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = -\frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{8}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: is this answer the same as $z=\frac{-25+i√3}{16}$ and $z=\frac{-25-i√3}{16}$

Comment: No, you have to solve an equation $(2z + 3)^3 = \frac{1}{64} \Rightarrow z = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{64}} - 3\right)$, and the formulas above give you the values of $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{64}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got it now, it's a property of the polynomial, the equation $z^2-1$ is satisfied by $z =1, z= -1$, because a quadratic has two roots

While $z^3-1$ is satisfied by $z=1$ as the obvious real solution, but a cubic has three roots, so the other two are unreal, but if we can factor it or substitute $z=a+bi$, to get the remaining roots
$$ z^2+z+1$$
$$ z_1 = -\frac{1}{2}  + \frac{\sqrt{ -3}}{2}$$
$$ z_2 = -\frac{1}{2}  - \frac{\sqrt{ -3}}{2}$$
They are conjugate of eachother, If you cube it using the property of complex number the result is $z^3 = 1$, so $z_0 , z_1, z_2$ all from the cube root of unity

Anytime you take the cube root of a number $n$, the solutions are $\sqrt[3]{n} , \sqrt[3]{n} \cdot z_1, \sqrt[3]{n} \cdot z_2$